# Importing existing data model into geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-9.3, esri-geodatabase, schema-architecture, arcgis-data-model

How can I integrate an existing ArcGIS datamodel like **[Arc Marine](http://dusk.geo.orst.edu/djl/arcgis/)** into my geodatabase? I don't have schematics in my ArcGIS 9.3.1.

Comment: Are you still using ArcGIS 9.3 to try and do this?  If not, what ArcGIS for Desktop version are you using?  What have you tried to do so far?  What type of geodatabase are you using?  You can use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with these details.